# How to use data in external javascript file from express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating application using node.js express where i want to pass some data from express and use in external javascript file.

here is my app.js

```
const express=require('express');

const path=require('path');

const app=express();

const bodyParser=require('body-parser');

//configure app
 app.set('view engine','ejs');
 app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

//use middleware
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//define routes


var arrayData = [
    { id: 1, desc: "Nitesh" },
   {id:2,desc:"Raviaknt"}
]




app.get('/',function(req,res){

      res.render('index', arrayData);

});




app.listen(800,function(){

    console.log('hi');

})
```

here is my index.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

       <script src="demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my last demo.js file

here how do i use arrayData which am passing in express

Comment: You can pass your data by inserting it in some hidden element in your template file and then picking and parsing that value on front end using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Place `<script type='text/javascript'>var arrData =<%-JSON.stringify(arrayData)%></script>` inside your `index.ejs` and see if it works.

Comment: @DavidR 
arrayData is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, in your `app.js` you need to change your  `app.get('/'...)` as `app.get('/',function(req,res){res.render('index',{arrayData: arrayData});});`

Comment: Yes after that it is working only in index.ejs but any idea how to use in external js file which is linked in index.ejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put it somewhere that the JavaScript can access it. (The JavaScript being external isn't particularly relevant).

At the moment, you are passing it to the template renderer and then ignoring it.

Generally, you should be passing an object to the template renderer, not an array, so you would want something more like this:

```
res.render('index', { myArray: arrayData });
```

How you then access it depends on exactly which template engine you are using.

There are several ways you could inject it into the page.

- You could create visible data, possibly by generating a table element with associated rows and data cells.
- You could store it in `<meta>` elements, or in `data-*` attributes.
- You could generate a `<script>` element and make it a global variable.

Note that with the latter two approaches you will either be better off serialising the data to a JSON string or doing so it a pretty hard requirement for the technique to work.

You could also forget about injecting it into the page and make it available through seperate URL that just outputs it as JSON. You could then have the client side JavaScript use XMLHttpRequest or fetch to request it.

Comment: after your suggestion its working fine when putting like this in index.ejs  <script type='text/javascript'>
  var arrayData =<%-JSON.stringify(myArray)%>
       alert("somevalue"+arrayData);   but it does not work when i put this code in  demo.js file any idea about ?

Comment: @Deepak — `demo.js` is being rendered by `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and not by `res.render('index', { myArray: arrayData });`. It isn't template file and you aren't passing any data to it from the express route.

Comment: I am new in this can you please help me what code i have to write so that i can access that data in  my external javascript file

Comment: You'd need to write an Express route in the style of app.get('/',function(req,res){ to do it. It's probably not a good idea though. Keeping your data separate from your logic makes things easier to manage.

Comment: Then according to you what is the best way to get access data in external Js file from express.if there is  any blog then share so that i can learn and can do it.

Comment: Depends on the data, how closely it is tied to the page, and what you want to do with it. There are four different approaches mentioned in this answer because they all have their place.

Comment: Is there any link from where i can learn, I am new so i can learn this and make application like that